# Get parts that generate by all suppliers

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Parts table

```
pid
____
10
20
30
```

Suppliers table

```
sid
____
1
2
3
```

Cataglog table

```
cid|pid|sid
___________
1  | 10  | 1
2  | 10  | 2
3  | 10  | 3
4  | 20  | 1
5  | 20  | 2
```

I want get parts that generate by all suppliers

I want result 10 for this sample...

I write this query ([demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5035b1/1))

```
select p.pid,count(c.pid) from  p join  c on(c.pid=p.pid)
group by c.pid
having count(c.pid) = (select count(1) from s)
```

Question:there is better way to get parts that generate by all suppliers.

Comment: expected results?.

Answer (score 1):

One improvement could be handling `c.sid` duplicates:

```
having count(distinct c.sid) = (select count(1) from s)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the the product IDs (pid), you don't have to join. You could do it just on the catalog table like:

```
   SELECT pid 
     FROM c 
 GROUP BY pid
   HAVING count(DISTINCT sid) = (SELECT count(DISTINCT sid) FROM s)
```